# recoding numbers to strings does not replace all values

Tags: r

Can someone explain why only some of the numbers are being converted to the strings high and low?

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(npitotal=ceiling(runif(30,0,40)))
df$npitotal[df$npitotal >= 22] <- "high"
df$npitotal[df$npitotal < 22] <- "low"

df$npitotal
# [1] "low"  "low"  "high" "high" "9"    "high" "high" "high"
# [9] "high" "3"    "9"    "8"    "high" "low"  "high" "low" 
#[17] "high" "high" "low"  "high" "high" "9"    "high" "6"   
#[25] "low"  "low"  "low"  "low"  "high" "low"
```

Comment: After you do your first conversion it becomes a character vector - so the second less than is not being evaluated numerically but as a character.

Comment: As an alternative, take a look at `?findInterval` and `?cut`

Comment: @thelatemail, 'cut' doesnt seem like it will let you specify the break point.

Comment: @Rilcon42 - of course it can - `cut(df$npitotal, c(-Inf,22,Inf), labels=c("low","high"), right=FALSE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My eventual solution was to use `recode` in the car package:

```
library(car)
recode(df$npitotal,"0:21='low';22:40='high'")
```

Note that 0:21 is [0,21] (so 20.99 evaluates to "low: in this case)

Thanks to @Jay for explaining the reason this causes a problem:

After you do your first conversion it becomes a character vector - so the second less than is not being evaluated numerically but as a character.